# Linking to content's static route in Astro

Tags: astrojs

I'm exploring moving a blog to Astro. My existing permalinks are of the form `/blog/:year/:month/:day/:slug/`, like `/blog/2023/07/16/my-post/`.

I created the file `/pages/blog/[year]/[month]/[day]/[slug].astro` and in that file I defined `getStaticPaths()`:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const posts = await getCollection("blog");
    return posts.map((post) => {
        let pubDate = post.data.pubDate;
        let slug = (post.slug.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-(.+)/)||[])[1] || post.slug;

        return {
            params: {
                year: String(pubDate.getFullYear()).padStart(4, "0"),
                month: String(pubDate.getMonth()).padStart(2, "0"),
                day: String(pubDate.getDay()).padStart(2, "0"),
                slug: slug,
            },
            props: post,
        };
    });
}
```

That correctly generates the on-disk structure I expect:

```
▶ src/pages/blog/[year]/[month]/[day]/[slug].astro
  ├─ /blog/2022/06/05/markdown-style-guide/index.html (+17ms)
  ├─ /blog/2022/06/06/using-mdx/index.html (+23ms)
  ├─ /blog/2022/06/05/first-post/index.html (+27ms)
  ├─ /blog/2022/06/05/third-post/index.html (+31ms)
  └─ /blog/2022/06/05/second-post/index.html (+34ms)
```

Suppose I want an index of blog posts. The example template uses:

```
<ul>
    {
        posts.map((post) => (
            <li>
                <FormattedDate date={post.data.pubDate} />
                <a href={`/blog/${post.slug}/`}>{post.data.title}</a>
            </li>
        ))
    }
</ul>
```

However in my structure, the URL is not `/blog/${post.slug}/` so the link is broken.

How could I automatically generate the correct link according to the static route format?

The `post` object does not contain its canonical URL, nor did I notice an API for generating a URL from the `post.slug` or `post.id`. Do I need to provide this myself?

Comment: Can you get the `year`, `month`, `day` from  the `post` object's `pubDate` the same way you did for individual posts and build the url from those?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible in Astro 2.0 to generate these links automatically, or to generate the slugs in the way that I want. See ["Option to decor relate slugs from filesystem"](https://github.com/withastro/roadmap/discussions/516) for some related discussion.